# PostreSQL - "Operator does not exist: character varying = character varying[]: when passing array to ANY?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a plpgsql function that returns a varchar[]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_distr_parents(distr_id character varying)
 RETURNS character varying[]
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
        all_ids VARCHAR[];
        parent_id VARCHAR(6);
        cur_id VARCHAR(6) := distr_id;
BEGIN
    all_ids := all_ids || distr_id;
    parent_id := (SELECT dl.parent_distr_id  FROM distribution_list dl WHERE dl.id  = distr_id);

        WHILE (parent_id IS NOT NULL) LOOP
            all_ids := all_ids || parent_id;
            cur_id := parent_id;
            parent_id := (SELECT dl.parent_distr_id  FROM distribution_list dl WHERE dl.id  = cur_id);
        END LOOP;
    
    RETURN all_ids;
END;
$function$
;
```

The function seems to work as expected (e.g. it returns an array such as `{2,1}`).

However, I am trying to perform a query that returns records whose ID is in the returned array:

```
SELECT * FROM distribution_list dl 
WHERE dl.id =  ANY((SELECT get_distr_parents('5305')));
```

This query returns an error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = character varying[]
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 50
```

However, the following executes just fine:

```
SELECT * FROM distribution_list dl 
WHERE dl.id =  ANY(ARRAY((SELECT get_distr_parents('5305'))));
```

While the above works, I would rather avoid having to wrap it in an ARRAY every time (especially since I plan using this in a Java program).

What am I missing? If the function already returns an array, why does wrapping it in `ARRAY()` change the behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `dl.id =  ANY(get_distr_parents('5305'))`

Comment: Or change the function to return `SETOF character varying` and use `IN (SELECT get_distr_parents('5305'))`.

Comment: Thanks so much @a_horse_with_no_name. So simple, yet I spent more time than I care to admit trying to research and resolve the issue. Could not find documentation that matched my exact case.